# How to attach an event handler only once continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem I hope to solve it when I put the indicator to the input triggers the event fire more than once where I want to triggers the event only once continuously thank you for your cooperation with me and this is the code

```
<label for="price-exposed-min">
    <div class="zsg-content_collapsed zsg-form-field">
        <input type="tel" id="price-exposed-min" aria-labelledby="price-exposed-min" value="" placeholder="Min" autocomplete="off" tabindex="10">
        <p class="zsg-form-error-text">Enter a valid number</p>
    </div>
    <ul id="min-options" class="filter-options" style="display: block;">
        <li tabindex="11">$0+</li>
        <li tabindex="12">$100,000+</li>
        <li tabindex="13">$200,000+</li>
        <li tabindex="14">$300,000+</li>
        <li tabindex="15">$400,000+</li>
        <li tabindex="16">$500,000+</li>
        <li tabindex="17">$600,000+</li>
        <li tabindex="18">$700,000+</li>
        <li tabindex="19">$800,000+</li>
        <li tabindex="20">$900,000+</li>
    </ul>
</label>
```

```
$(document).off('focus', '#price-exposed-min').on('focus', '#price-exposed-min', function() {
            alert(1);
});
```

Note: Whenever I click on the input box I want the message alert appear once and when I click again it also appears once.

Comment: so you only want a function to run once?

Comment: Whenever I click on the input box I want the message alert appear once and when I click again it also appears once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `focus` with `click` and it will trigger only once each time.

```
$(document).off('focus', '#price-exposed-min').on('click', '#price-exposed- 
min', function() {
        alert(1);
});
```

Bdw if you just want a function to run once every time, you can skip the off method. Just using the .on() will also do the job, that's the correct way to bind a function to the input.

```
$(document).on('click', '#price-exposed-min', function() {
        alert(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use click instead of focus:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#price-exposed-once', function(){ 
        alert(1);
    )};
```